# Display table with data in it after product detail

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

Magento 1.9.1.0 
I am new to magento. i want to display data in table after product detail. I have created table in database. I can add data from backend/admin panel side. now i want to display this data in product detail page after product. Below is attached image with data that i want to display.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are working with user defined module, then in frontend layout xml, you can write code like ...

```
 <catalog_product_view>
        <update handle="content"/>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="tabledata/tabledata" after="-" name="tabledata" template="tabledata/tabledata.phtml" />
        </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

If not using module, then go to catalog layout and override the layout file, and add the above content's section code.

you will need to create a phtml file for template, that 'll show the data. and xml used where to show the data.